# Issues with the exe file created by the pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

hi have a python script which I converted to .exe file using pyinstaller. It has three dependencies and this is how I bundle them together

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "dependencies1.py;." --add-data "dependencies2.py;." --add-data "dependencies3.py;." --hidden-import "babel.numbers" --onefile -w mainScript.py
```

All these python files are on my local drive, and the generated exe file works just fine (takes about 5-8 seconds to run)! The mainScript also pulls data from a couple of excel file but they are in common drive (Y:) so I dont bundle them while creating my .exe file

The problem starts when I move the .exe file to the common drive (Y:) and when I click on it, it takes about 8 "mintues" to run. I am v new to all this so absolutely no clue how to fix it. Any advice will be high appreciated.

Again, the exe file runs fine - just that takes about 6 secs on local drive vs 8 minutes on common drive!